# Binding returned server response with the lightning dataTable

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am getting list of objects(type="string") from the apex controller to the component, now I have to bind the response in the table to display the data in a column. I used , now table is populating but data is not rendered in the column.

I have customobject "Monitoring__c" having two fields "ProfileName__c"(picklist) and "ObjectName__c".

UseCase: I am displaying all the objects which have READ access on the profile selected from the picklist.

Component.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="ConfigMonitoring" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="tableCols" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="ObjectName" type="string[]" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="objInfo" type="Monitoring__c" default="{sobjectType : 'Monitoring__c'}" />
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select Profile</label>
<div class="slds-select_container">
<ui:inputSelect  aura:id="ProfileName" class="slds-select"  change="{!c.onPicklistChange}"/>
</div>
</div>    
<div tabindex="-1" class="slds-scrollable_y" style="width: 902px;">
<lightning:datatable data="{!v.ObjectName}"
                             columns="{!v.tableCols}"
                             keyField="Id"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

</div>
</aura:component>
```

ApexController:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static list<string> getProfileWithObjects(string pfr){
    List<string> ObpermList = new List<string>();
    // map<string,string> obmap = new map<string,string>();
    for(ObjectPermissions obp : [SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsDelete
                                FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment))
                                AND
                                (PermissionsRead = true)
                                AND
                                ( Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true)
                                AND
                                (Parent.Profile.Name = :pfr)]){

           //ObpermList.add(obp.Parent.Profile.Name);
           ObpermList.add(obp.SObjectType);

           //obmap.put(obp.Parent.Profile.Name,obp.SObjectType);   
     }
    system.debug('**********'+ObpermList[1]);
    return ObpermList;
}
```

JS Controller:

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchPickListVal(component, 'ProfileName__c', 'ProfileName');

    var cols = [
        {label: 'Object Names', fieldName: 'ObjectName__c', type: 'text'}
        ];
    component.set("v.tableCols", cols);
},
onPicklistChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    // get the value of select option
    var PrfName = event.getSource().get("v.value");       

    var action =  component.get("c.getProfileWithObjects");
  // set param to method  
    action.setParams({
        'pfr': PrfName
      });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set('v.ObjectName',storeResponse);
            alert(storeResponse);
        }

    });
  // enqueue the Action  
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}})
```

Here I am getting the value from the apex controller and able to see in the picklist. On selecting the profile value from picklist I can see all the objects in the alert. So controller and component is just working fine. Now when I am putting the fetched response in the lighting:dataTable it rendered the blank table.

[image: Alert showing all the object having read access on the seelcted profile.]

[image: Blank table with no data]

How can I populate the data in the table?

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript controller you are using **ObjectName__c** for FieldName but here you need to use the Field API Name of the field that you wanted to display. In your case it should be **SObjectType** 
Use below code for the doInit Method

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchPickListVal(component, 'ProfileName__c', 'ProfileName');

    var cols = [
        {label: 'Object Name', fieldName: 'SObjectType', type: 'text'}
        ];
    component.set("v.tableCols", cols);
}
```

Also, use below code for Apex Class

```
@AuraEnabled
public static list<ObjectPermissions> getProfileWithObjects(string pfr){
    List<string> ObpermList = new List<string>();
    // map<string,string> obmap = new map<string,string>();
    List<ObjectPermissions> opjPermissionList = [SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsDelete
                                FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment))
                                AND
                                (PermissionsRead = true)
                                AND
                                ( Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true)
                                AND
                                (Parent.Profile.Name = :pfr)]

    system.debug('**********'+ObpermList[1]);
    return opjPermissionList;
}
```

Comment: Field API name is "ObjectName__c" using the correct one. But tried with "SObjectType" as well not working.

Comment: I am sorry I was not able to explain about the API name. Let me try once again. We need to put the API name of the response Object. For example, in the Question, you are fetching the SObjectType From ObjectPermissions object so we need to use SObjectType. 

Also, in the Apex Class you are returning List<String> return list<ObjectPermissions>.

Updated the answer with apex class code

Comment: Thank you so much Amit for your quick attention on it. I decided to remove <lightning:dataTable> and used html <table> instead and it is working fine now.